# Select a value in a first table according to another value of a second table (sql)

Tags: mysql, sql

let me explain my situation, it really clearer than the title!  I have two tables. Let give a look here and than I will you explain what I would like to do.

First table (lesson table)

```
+------------------+----------------+
| LessonCode       | SubjectCode    |
+------------------+----------------+
| 1                | 10             |
| 2                | 11             |
| 3                | 12             |
+------------------+----------------+
```

Second table (subject table)

```
+------------------+----------------+------------+
| subjectCode      | SubjectName    | teacherCode|
+------------------+----------------+------------+
| 10               | Maths          | 15         |
| 11               | English        | 20         |
| 12               | Greek          | 30         |
+------------------+----------------+------------+
```

I would select from table `lesson` the subject that has `teacherCode=20`. It is possible in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all lessons of teacher X, you will have to join both tables:

```
select LessonCode from lesson l
inner join subject s on s.subjectCode = l.SubjectCode
where s.teacherCode = x
```

This basically does the following: It creates the cross product of the two tables and then deletes all lines which do not comply with the `on` clause. Then it deletes all lines which do not comply with the `where` clause. This leaves only lessons of a given teacher X.

Comment: Thank you for your help. And why if a do `select * from lesson l ..` I have as result a unique unified table with all both tables columns ?

Comment: Yes, you will. Just try it on your DBMS.

Comment: I misread your comment and missed the `why`... `Select *` will get all columns of all joined tables, `select t.*` will get all columns of table `t` (which must appear in the from/join clause), `select x` will yield the column `x` if it appears in only one of the joined tables, `select t.x` will retrieve the column `x` of the table `t`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * 
from lesson l
join subject s on s.subjectCode=l.SubjectCode
where s.teacherCode=20
```

Comment: The column `SubjectCode` of table `lesson` is with uppercase `S`.

Comment: I don't think mySQL is case-sensitive in column names, but I fixed the example just to be safe

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a simple join.

```
select l.*
from lesson l
join subject s on l.SubjectCode=s.SubjectCode
where s.teacherCode=20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    (lesson, subject)
WHERE 
    lesson.SubjectCode = subject.subjectCode AND
    subject.teacherCode = 20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SubjectCode     
from  LessonTbl lt
Left Outer join  subjectTbl st
on       lt.subjectCode    = st.subjectCode      
where st.teacherCode=20.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM lesson A
JOIN subject B ON A.SubjectCode = B.SubjectCode
WHERE B.teacherCode = '20'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select a.*
From Lesson a
Inner Join Subject b on a.SubjectCode = b.SubjectCode
where c.TeacherCode = '20'
```

That's all. As long as you know that every Lesson's SubjectCode exists in the Subject table, just do an Inner Join like in my example. Otherwise, change it to a Left Outer Join.